# Edit a record in a datatable in shiny r

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I have two datatables in my shiny app in the first datatable I can edit,add , delete data very well, but in the second data  table when I  want to select a row to edit the table it does not show anything in the textinput to edit it. 
I think that it is because of similar names of some parameters in same functions. But I do not know where is my problem? Here is the link of:[CRUD](http://www.r-bloggers.com/shiny-crud-app/)

The update function for first datatable is as following:

```
 UpdateInputs <- function(data, session) {
   updateTextInput(session, "id", value = unname(rownames(data)))
   updateTextInput(session, "name", value = unname(data["name"]))
   updateCheckboxInput(session, "used_shiny", value = as.logical(data["used_shiny"]))
   updateSliderInput(session, "r_num_years", value = as.integer(data["r_num_years"]))
 }

UpdateData <- function(data) {
   data <- CastData(data)
   responses[row.names(responses) == row.names(data), ] <<- data
 }
```

Similar new functions for second datatable

```
UpdateInputs1 <- function(data, session) {
   updateTextInput(session, "id1", value = unname(rownames(data)))
   updateTextInput(session, "name1", value = unname(data["name1"]))
 }


 UpdateData1 <- function(data) {
   data <- CastData1(data)
   responses2[row.names(responses2) == row.names(data), ] <<- data
 }
```

Server.R

```
# Press "New" button -> display empty record
  observeEvent(input$new, {
    UpdateInputs(CreateDefaultRecord(), session)
  })
 # Select row in table -> show details in inputs
  observe({if (length(input$responses_rows_selected) > 0) 
    { 
    data <- ReadData()[input$responses_rows_selected, ] 
    UpdateInputs(data, session) }
    })

# Press "New" button -> display empty record
  observeEvent(input$new1, {
    UpdateInputs1(CreateDefaultRecord1(), session)
  })
 # Select row in table -> show details in inputs
  observeEvent(input$responses2_rows_selected, {
    if (length(input$responses2_rows_selected) > 0) {
      data <- ReadData1()[input$responses2_rows_selected, ]
      UpdateInputs1(data, session)
    }})
```

Comment: Is the problem because of global Assign  <<- ?

Comment: The problem is in the Select row in table -> show details in inputs